# Image and Title hidden when using clip-path: polygon HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Whenever I change the attribute `"calc (100% - 90 vw)"` (changing from 90 to 10, for example) the blue part of the page changes. But the title is hidden and only part of it appears depending on what I change it to. How do I change it without hiding the text?

Here's my code:

```css
div.front-page {
  background-color: #cddaee;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 calc(100% - 2vw));
  /* height: 500px; */
}

div#header h1,
h2 {
  margin-left: 2.5in;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: "Times News Roman";
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <div class="running-h1-title"></div>
  <div class="running-h2-title"></div>

  <div class="front-page">
    <div id="header" class="title-page">
      <h1 class="title">Untitled</h1>
      <h2 class="author">Me</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="front-matter-container">
  </div>

  <div class="main">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: use pixel instead of vw

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks for your time. But this doesnt work, when I change part of the title gets hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the clip-path with a skew transformation on a pseudo element using the `h2` as reference so that you keep the same angle and origin even if you resize the screen:

For the trick to work you need to make the h2 `inline-block` and expand the pseudo element using big values to cover the whole area.

```css
div.front-page {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.front-page h2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0;
}

div.front-page h2:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: -100vh;
  left: -100vw;
  right: -100vw;
  bottom: 7px;
  background: #cddaee;
  transform: skewY(1deg);
}

div#header h1,
h2 {
  margin-left: 2.5in;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: "Times News Roman";
}
```

```html
<div class="front-page">
  <div id="header" class="title-page">
    <h1 class="title">Untitled</h1>
    <h2 class="author">Me</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks. Could help me with one thing? How I can manage to have a diagonal from bottom right to left top? The page should bem half blue half white. How I control this?